# Avoid to get "system.indexes" as a collection name in casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I'm using `casbah` to find collection names in a mongodb-database

```
    val mongoClient = MongoClient()
    val db = mongoClient("db_name")
    val coll = db.collectionNames()
```

It also gives 'system.indexes' because each mongo database has that one. Is there any way to get rid from this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to filter it by yourself.

```
val coll = db.collectionNames().filterNot(_.startsWith("system."))
```